# Function with jquery.alphanumeric

Tags: jquery, alphanumeric

i wanto implement jquery.alphanumeric in html pattern, so i use jquery plugin from [here](https://github.com/johnantoni/jquery.alphanumeric),

this is my code

```
<input type="text" char-allow="$#*" class="alpha">
<input type="text" char-allow="+-" class="numeric">
<input type="text" char-allow="&" class="alphanumeric">

<script>
    function setAlphaNumeric(){
        $(".numeric").each(function(){
            var a = $(this).attr("char-allow"); $(this).numeric({allow:a});
        });
        $(".alpha").each(function(){
            var a = $(this).attr("char-allow"); $(this).alpha({allow:a});
        });
        $(".alphanumeric").each(function(){
            var a = $(this).attr("char-allow"); $(this).alphanumeric({allow:a});
        });
    }

$(function(){

setAlphaNumeric();

});
</script>
```

is there any shortest & best than that code?

Comment: This question doesn't belong here. Consider moving it to Code Review.

Comment: This question should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't create custom attributes like `char-allow`, use HTML5 data attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, with jQuery and a little simple use of RegEx, you really don't need a plugin for this. It's extremely simple.

> Update! Here's a quick breakdown of first example.

- `$(document).on`: Here, I'm simply making use of the DOM's `document` variable to assign events via jQuery [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) feature. This is a handy way to ensure that even elements loaded after the DOM is finished loading (dynamic elements) will still adhere to the given event task.
- `.on('keydown', '.alpha'`: The first 2 params are our [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) and our [selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), respectively. I chose the `keydown` event because we can control whether or not to even show a character by returning a `boolean` value. IF `false` is returned, then no character will be printed to the UI.
- `var a = e.key;`: jQuery Events is nice enough to translate to String what character is being asked for. Here, I simply assign that String to a variable for checking!
- `if (a.length == 1)`: The reason for this is simple, if the String is longer than 1 or less than 1, then it's not a character. You can see this yourself by using something like `console.debug(a);` in the Event method, and then watching your console as you type in the input. For example, a <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key will have a String of `"Backspace"`.

### The RegEx's:

1. `/[a-z]|\$|#|\*/i`:  ***alpha***

   - `[a-z]`: Looks for all lower case letters `a` through `z`
   - `|\$|#|\*`: Includes your "allowed" characters, using `|` as an "OR" separator. A Backslash is needed for the `$` and `*` characters in order to *escape* them in the RegEx statements; otherwise they have an entirely different meaning of their own.
   - `/i`: This little suffix tells our RegEx to **ignore** the case of the characters. So our beginning statement no longer cares if it's Lower or Upper case.
2. `/[0-9]|\+|-/`:  ***numeric***

   - `[0-9]`: Looks for each digit, `0` through `9`
   - `|\+|-`: Much the same as the alphabet one, this is your extra "allowed" characters, separated by an `|` (OR) operator.
3. `/[a-z]|[0-9]|&/i`:  ***alphanumeric***

   - `[a-z]`: Looks for all lower case letters `a` through `z`
   - `|[0-9]`: Or looks for each digit, `0` through `9`
   - `|&`: Again, checks for your allowed character.
   - `/i`: And again, ignore all case issues.

---

**Example 1**:

```js
$(document)
 .on('keydown', '.alpha', function(e) {
  var a = e.key;
  if (a.length == 1) return /[a-z]|\$|#|\*/i.test(a);
  return true;
 })
 .on('keydown', '.numeric', function(e) {
  var a = e.key;
  if (a.length == 1) return /[0-9]|\+|-/.test(a);
  return true;
 })
 .on('keydown', '.alphanumeric', function(e) {
  var a = e.key;
  if (a.length == 1) return /[a-z]|[0-9]|&/i.test(a);
  return true;
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr />
<label for="inpAlpha">Alpha</label>
<input id="inpAlpha" type="text" char-allow="$#*" class="alpha" />
<hr />
<label for="inpNumeric">Num</label>
<input id="inpNumeric" type="text" char-allow="+-" class="numeric" />
<hr />
<label for="inpAlphaNum">Alpha Num</label>
<input id="inpAlphaNum" type="text" char-allow="&" class="alphanumeric" />
<hr />
```

Or with everything combined in one method, **Example 2**:

```js
$(document)
 .on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
  var a = e.key;
  if (a.length == 1) switch (true) {
   case $(this).hasClass('alpha'):
    return /[a-z]|\$|#|\*/i.test(a);
    break;
   case $(this).hasClass('numeric'):
    return /[0-9]|\+|-/.test(a);
    break;
   case $(this).hasClass('alphanumeric'):
    return /[a-z]|[0-9]|&/i.test(a);
    break;
  }
  return true;
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr />
<label for="inpAlpha">Alpha</label>
<input id="inpAlpha" type="text" char-allow="$#*" class="alpha" />
<hr />
<label for="inpNumeric">Num</label>
<input id="inpNumeric" type="text" char-allow="+-" class="numeric" />
<hr />
<label for="inpAlphaNum">Alpha Num</label>
<input id="inpAlphaNum" type="text" char-allow="&" class="alphanumeric" />
<hr />
```

---

---

> And, just for the heck of it, if you really do want a jQuery Plugin, I made a couple very simple ones. The first one is even more simplistic than the Plugin referred to by OP. See [**My Github**](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/Simple-jQuery-Alpha-Numeric-Inputs) for a bit more detailed info than below.

#### †[Most Simplistic Version](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/Simple-jQuery-Alpha-Numeric-Inputs#simple-jquery-alpha-numeric-inputs):

This first version is barely 20 lines of code, and could even be *[minified](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/)* to be much smaller **<sub>[[QuickLink]](https://cdn.rawgit.com/JDMcKinstry/Simple-jQuery-Alpha-Numeric-Inputs/master/jQuery.alphanumeric.min.js)</sub>**. It's very simplistic in that you only need to assign 1 of 3 classes to any input, `[ 'alpha', 'numeric', 'alphanumeric' ]`. If you want extra characters allowed, then simply add an HTML5 data attribute of "allow" and give it the value of the extra characters to allow. 
Like so: `<input class="alpha" data-allow="$#*" type="text" />`

```js
;(function($) {
 var regEx = {
   alpha: new RegExp('[a-z]', 'i'),
   numeric: new RegExp('[0-9]'),
   alphanumeric: new RegExp('[a-z]|[0-9]', 'i')
  }
 function procInput(a, b, c) {
  switch(!0) {
   case a.hasClass('alpha'):
    return c ? 0 <= c.indexOf(b) || regEx.alpha.test(b) : regEx.alpha.test(b);
   case a.hasClass('numeric'):
    return c ? 0 <= c.indexOf(b) || regEx.numeric.test(b) : regEx.numeric.test(b);
   case a.hasClass('alphanumeric'):
    return c ? 0 <= c.indexOf(b) || regEx.alphanumeric.test(b) : regEx.alphanumeric.test(b);
  }
  return !0;
 }
 $(document).on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
  var a = $(this), b = e.key, c = a.data('allow');
  return (!e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey) && 1 == b.length ? procInput(a, b, c) : !0;
 });
})(jQuery);

/* The following will "dynamically" make the second Alpha input an alpha only input 3 seconds after load is finished. This shows hwo the event assignment is versatile.  */
setTimeout(function() { $('#inpAlphaB').val('').addClass('alpha'); }, 3e3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr />
<label for="inpAlpha">Alpha</label>
<input id="inpAlpha" type="text" data-allow="$#*" class="alpha" />
<hr />
<label for="inpAlphaB">Alpha B</label>
<input id="inpAlphaB" type="text" /> <sub>Is made "alpha" class 3 seconds after load.</sub>
<hr />
<label for="inpNumeric">Num</label>
<input id="inpNumeric" type="text" data-allow="+-" class="numeric" />
<hr />
<label for="inpAlphaNum">Alpha Num</label>
<input id="inpAlphaNum" type="text" data-allow="&" class="alphanumeric" />
<hr />
```

#### ‡[Extended Version](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/Simple-jQuery-Alpha-Numeric-Inputs#extended-version):

This version is a little more involved. Still pretty simplistic in that you need only assign classes and use the `data-allow="string"` attribute to allow extras. However, the main difference is that this version has its own **`Object`** that can be *`toggled`* on and off. It also has a feature in the very first line that allows you to set it to initially be *`on`* or *`off`* based on whether or not the first variable is **`true`** or **`false`**. This version will also *automatically* clean the value of alpha|numeric inputs when toggled *on*.

```js
;(function($) { // $.inputAlphaNumeric // set first variable "initializeON" to bool to toggle on || off from document.ready
 var initializeON = true;
 
 function __event(e) {
  return $.inputAlphaNumeric.keydown.event.apply($.inputAlphaNumeric, [e, this]);
 }
 
 function adjustValue() { // clean up inputs when feature is toggled 'on'
  if (this.state) {
   var regEx = this.regEx;
   this.inputs.each(function() {
    var a = $(this), b = a.val(), c = a.data('allow');
    if (b != '') switch(!0) {
     case $(this).hasClass('alpha'):
      a.val( b.split('').filter(function(v) { if ((c && 0 <= c.indexOf(v)) || regEx.alpha.test(v)) return v; }).join('') );
      break;
     case $(this).hasClass('numeric'):
      a.val( b.split('').filter(function(v) { if ((c && 0 <= c.indexOf(v)) || regEx.numeric.test(v)) return v; }).join('') );
      break;
     case $(this).hasClass('alphanumeric'):
      a.val( b.split('').filter(function(v) { if ((c && 0 <= c.indexOf(v)) || regEx.alphanumeric.test(v)) return v; }).join('') );
      break;
    }
   });
  }
  return this;
 }
 
 function keyDown() {
  return { event: keyDownEvent, process: keyDownProcess }
 }
 function keyDownEvent(e, inp) {
  var a = $(inp), b = e.key, c = a.data('allow');
  return (!e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey) && 1 == b.length ? this.keydown.process.apply(this, [a, b, c]) : !0;
 }
 function keyDownProcess(a, b, c) {
  var regEx = this.regEx;
  switch(!0) {
   case a.hasClass('alpha'):
    return c ? 0 <= c.indexOf(b) || regEx.alpha.test(b) : regEx.alpha.test(b);
   case a.hasClass('numeric'):
    return c ? 0 <= c.indexOf(b) || regEx.numeric.test(b) : regEx.numeric.test(b);
   case a.hasClass('alphanumeric'):
    return c ? 0 <= c.indexOf(b) || regEx.alphanumeric.test(b) : regEx.alphanumeric.test(b);
  }
  return !0;
 }
 
 function inputAlphaNumeric(initOn) {
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
   __state: { enumerable: false, value: false, writable: true },
   adjustVal: {
    enumerable: false,
    value: adjustValue,
    writable: false
   },
   classes: { enumerable: true, get: function() { return [ 'alpha', 'numeric', 'alphanumeric' ]; } },
   inputs: { enumerable: true, get: function() { return $(this.selector); } },
   keydown: { enumerable: false, get: keyDown },
   off: { value: function() { return this.toggle('off'); } },
   on: { value: function() { return this.toggle('on'); } },
   regEx: {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function() {
     return {
      alpha: new RegExp('[a-z]', 'i'),
      numeric: new RegExp('[0-9]'),
      alphanumeric: new RegExp('[a-z]|[0-9]', 'i')
     }
    }
   },
   selector: { enumerable: true, get: function() { return '.' + this.classes.join(', .'); } },
   state: {
    get: function() { return this.__state; },
    set: function(onOff) {
     switch (typeof onOff) {
      case 'boolean':
       this.__state = onOff
       break;
      case 'string':
       switch (onOff) {
        case 'on':
         this.__state = true;
         break;
        case 'off':
         this.__state = false;
         break;
        default:
         this.__state = true;
       }
       break;
      default:
       this.__state = true;
     }
     return this;
    }
   },
   toggle: {
    value: function(onOff) {
     this.state = void 0 == onOff ? !this.state : onOff;
     $(document)[this.state ? 'on' : 'off']('keydown', 'input', __event);
     return this.adjustVal();
    }
   }
  });
  if (initOn) this.on();
  return this;
 }
 
 $.inputAlphaNumeric = new inputAlphaNumeric(initializeON);
})(jQuery);

// checkbox to toggle feature on and off
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function(e) { var a = $.inputAlphaNumeric.toggle(this.checked); if (window['console'] && console.debug) console.debug(a); });
// sets initial state of checkbox based on whether or not feature is on or off
$('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $.inputAlphaNumeric.state);

setTimeout(function() { $('#inpAlphaB').val('').addClass('alpha'); }, 3e3);

$.each($.inputAlphaNumeric, function(k,v) { console.debug(k + ":\t", v); });
console.debug("$.inputAlphaNumeric:\t", $.inputAlphaNumeric);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="inpAlpha">Alpha</label>
<input id="inpAlpha" type="text" data-allow="$#* " class="alpha" /><!--Notice I added a "space" value as well-->
<hr />
<label for="inpAlphaB">Alpha B</label>
<input id="inpAlphaB" type="text" /> <sub>Is made "alpha" class 3 seconds after load.</sub>
<hr />
<label for="inpNumeric">Num</label>
<input id="inpNumeric" type="text" data-allow="+-" class="numeric" />
<hr />
<label for="inpAlphaNum">Alpha Num</label>
<input id="inpAlphaNum" type="text" data-allow="&" class="alphanumeric" />
<hr />
<label for="inpAlphaNumToggle">Alpha Num</label>
<input id="inpAlphaNumToggle" type="checkbox" />
<hr />
```

Comment: didnt get attr from "char-allow"

Comment: @AbuAyyub No I didn't. I'm sorry I didn't take more time to explain, I usually do. However, if you'll look at the regex statements, I already included your individual "char-allow" statements. I'll try and update this answer shortly and give a more thorough explanation. Hope you found it helpful! And remember, while they are often easy, sometimes a plugin is more than you really need and can just lead to more bloat.

Comment: @AbuAyyub Finally got that update on. Hope that helps a bit. Just ask me if you still don't understand something or want to better understand something.

Comment: @AbuAyyub Just for fun, if you still want some form of plugin instead, you might scroll to end of answer. Updated it with a little info and links to a [GitHub](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/Simple-jQuery-Alpha-Numeric-Inputs) repo I made for a very simple plugin of this. Well, 2 actually. The first version is basically just a self wrapped version of my previously given **`Example 2`**. The second version is a little more structured and comes with a simple option to toggle it on and off. See the [Readme](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/Simple-jQuery-Alpha-Numeric-Inputs/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: You can still paste any character.